# How to open Word document in server and modify?

Tags: javascript, php, ms-word, phpword

I am trying to open a word document in server,do modification and save that in server itself.. I have tried with phpword,but it opens the document offline and if the MSWord is not installed in our PC it is not able to open that document.
Is there any way to open the .docx in browser and do modification using php

Comment: you are looking for a word WYSIWYG editor for a php app or website?

Comment: Using the Word application server-side is not supported. So it's best to work with the Word Open XML file directly. There is an Open XML SDK for Javascript, for example.

Comment: For editing in browser Sir @Clint

Comment: would https://developers.google.com/drive/ work?

Comment: Thank you for your replies @Clint .. I added a extension in Chrome browser, which opens document and save it offline and then used php to upload that to my database